# Radio button validation causing rest of validation to fail

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, validation

The radio validation works but then the rest don't. What have I done wrong?

```
function validateRadio(radios) {
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
        if (radios[i].checked) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function validateForm() {
    if (validateRadio(document.forms["pancettaForm"]["updateShip"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please tell us how you would like to update your order.");
        return false;
    }
}

var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["order-number"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide your order number.");
    return false;
}
var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["full-name"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide your full name, or the recipients name if you are updating shipping information.");
    return false;
}
var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["phone"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide a phone number in case of delivery questions.");
    return false;
}
var display = document.getElementById('address').style.display;
if (display == 'block') {
    var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["address"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your address.");
        return false;
    }
}
var display = document.getElementById('city').style.display;
if (display == 'block') {
    var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["city"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your city.");
        return false;
    }
}
var display = document.getElementById('state').style.display;
if (display == 'block') {
    if (document.pancettaForm.state.value == "- Select State -") {
        alert("Please provide your state.");
        return false;
    }
}
var display = document.getElementById('zip').style.display;
if (display == 'block') {
    var x = document.forms["pancettaForm"]["zip"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your zip code.");
        return false;
    }
}
var display = document.getElementById('newShipDate').style.display;
if (display == 'block') {
    if (document.pancettaForm.state.value == "- Select Date -") {
        alert("Please choose your new shipping date.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So much code... a jsFiddle would be nice. Oh and some more information. Like what exactly fails?

Comment: It was truly obvious and no fiddle needed unless there are other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse the test so you do not have to return

```
    if(!validateRadio (document.forms["pancettaForm"]["updateShip"]))
            {
                alert("Please tell us how you would like to update your order.");
                return false;
            }

   // continue
```

You had the end bracket after the test of the radios so the rest of the script just floated in cyberspace

Also return true only once at the end and do not have var x multiple times and be consistent in how you access the form elements and I also fixed your date test which was testing state

```
function validateForm() {
  var x,display,form = document.forms["pancettaForm"];
  if (!validateRadio(form["updateShip"])) {
    alert("Please tell us how you would like to update your order.");
    return false;
  }

  x = form["order-number"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide your order number.");
    return false;
  }
  x = form["full-name"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide your full name, or the recipients name if you are updating shipping information.");
    return false;
  }
  x = form["phone"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please provide a phone number in case of delivery questions.");
    return false;
  }
  display = form["address"].style.display; 
  if (display == 'block') {
    x = form["address"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your address.");
        return false;
    }
  }
  display = form["city"].style.display;
  if (display == 'block') {
    x = form["city"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your city.");
        return false;
    }
  }
  display = form['state'].style.display;
  if (display == 'block') {
   x = form['state'].value;
    if (x == "- Select State -") {
        alert("Please provide your state.");
        return false;
    }
  }
  display = form['zip'].style.display;
  if (display == 'block') {
    x = form["zip"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please provide your zip code.");
        return false;
    }
  }
  display = form["newShipDate"].style.display;
  if (display == 'block') {
    x = form["newShipDate"].value;
    if (x.value == "- Select Date -") {
        alert("Please choose your new shipping date.");
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! i posted this just before i left work and the sloppiness is evidence of how sick i was of working on this! with fresh eyes and your help i've got the validation working.  however, when i use your code, only the order number, phone, and address validate. could that be because display and form are both declared to pancettaForm but the display is specific to the id?  my working form still has x declared each time. i do appreciate the suggestion to combine it and i will work on that when i have more time.

Comment: For this to work, you need a name on each field. Without seeing the form I cannot judge what might not work